# If I'm factoring $2p^2+p-10$ would the answer be $p(2p+5) -2(2p+5)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, solution-verification, quadratics

> If I'm factoring $2p^2+p-10$ would the answer be $p(2p+5) -2(2p+5)$?

And to check would I just distribute and see if it matches up to the original problem?

Comment: You need to set $(2p+5)$ as the common factor.

Comment: Factoring means writing the expression as a product, which you can do by collecting like terms to write $(p - 2)(2 p + 5)$. And yes, that's a fine way of checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can continue to factor by grouping the $2p+5$ terms:
$$p(2p+5)-2(2p+5) = (p-2)(2p+5)$$
From there you can multiply it out to check that it's equal to the original polynomial.